# What is the best practice to sharing types accross modules in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I was wondering what the best practice is to sharing types accross modules in typescript. I initally thought it be a good idea to export types in a types file, and include this types file among other modules, though, I am not sure if there is another way.
Thanks

Comment: i was building app where backend and frontend was separated but with same api type. both in typescript. so i created another project where was only api types on github and included it in be and fe in package.json.

Comment: with "modules" you refer to TypeScript modules or to TypeScript projects  ? (a project having its own tsconfig.json and package.json)

Comment: @cancerbero When I say "modules" I am referring to Typescript modules that have been imported in the same project.

Comment: Kyle, is not clear yet. Are you referring to other files that you just `import {foo} from './the/other/module'` ? or are you referring to other packages, like in `import {Component} from 'react'`. TypeScript ambient modules like in `declare module Foo` or plain old modules that just exported something like in export const c = 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your types are automatically shared between all files in a typescript project. You only need a ‘type definition’ file if you want to use an untyped javascript library. When working with modules you still need to use export and import of course.

Comment: Strange, this may be a vscode issue then... My type declarations do not seem to be shared between modules, and create nasty linting errors...

Comment: Can you share a link to the project or example ?